# Pandas rolling nunique to count the rolling sum of unique observations per year

Tags: python, pandas, unique, rolling-computation

Hi stack overflow community!

I have one question. I need to compute the rolling sum of unique observations per year. We want to know the number of unique employees on a project during the moving 12 months (rolling year).

My dataframe looks like this:

| date | employee_HK | Project |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-05-01 | 2 | 1 |
| 2020-05-01 | 3 | 1 |
| 2020-06-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-06-01 | 2 | 1 |
| 2020-06-01 | 3 | 1 |
| 2020-05-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020-05-01 | 2 | 2 |
| 2020-05-01 | 3 | 2 |
| 2020-06-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020-06-01 | 2 | 2 |
| 2020-06-01 | 3 | 2 |

I tried something like this:

```
df['MA_Employee'] = df.groupby('Project')['Employee_HK'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(12, 1).nunique())
```

but I get an error: AttributeError: 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'nunique'

I used to compute rolling aggregates using this code, just instead of nunique using sum() or mean(). I assume with nunique() there should be an another method to combine groupby, rolling and nunique.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you create a dataframe like the following: `df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-01-02', '2020-02-01'], 'employee': [1, 2]})`? It's easier to work with example then.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you meant.
But I think this could be what you look for:

```
# Load example data
df = pd.read_html("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72563945/pandas-rolling-nunique-to-count-the-rolling-sum-of-unique-observations-per-year", header=0, parse_dates=True)[0]

# calculate rolling nunique
df.groupby('Project')['employee_HK'].rolling(12, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: x.nunique())
```

(NB: the min periods is because your example does not have a year of data)

**output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for trying out! I also tried it this way with apply function, but then I get an error: DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: ok, what output do you get from df.info() it seems like one of your columns might have been loaded as text. Do you get too if you run the code i posted (with loading the example data)?